# Trying to concatenate a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a variable in Javascript. Here is my code:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
      let data = data+arr[i,j];
  }
}
```

The array arr has 10 rows and 9 columns and is filled with data. I want to create a new data string called data with all the values in the array arr.  Do you know why this doesn't work?

I tried using this code:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        let data = data+arr[i,j];
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have multidimensional arrays

Comment: a) declare `let data` outside of the loop b) initialise to an empty string c) only then, try concatenating to it inside the loop

Comment: How did you fill the `arr`? Please show us the code for that.

Comment: please add data `arr` and wanted result. arrays have only a single index. for nested arrays take for each level a single property accessor, like `arr[i][j]`.